# Query taxonomy of taxonomy of custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type called `ring_advantage`.

I have a custom taxonomy on `ring_advantage`, called `issue_RingAdvantage`

I have a custom taxonomy on `ring_advantage` called `topic`

I write an article under `ring_advantage`, pick an issue from `issue_RingAdvantage`, and pick a `topic`.

On the front-end, the user can land on a page that displays the information about `issue_RingAdvantage` (title, image, etc). On that same page, I want to display all articles that match the currently viewed `issue_RingAdvantage` AND the `topic` of the `ring_advantage` article.

I have the following query which successfully pulls in the articles attached to `issue_RingAdvantage`, but doesn't show the topics of the articles:

```
$current = get_terms(
    array(
        'taxonomy'      =>  'issue_RingAdvantage',
        'hide_empty'    =>  false,
        'orderby' => 'ID',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'number' => 1
    )
);

$args = array(
    'post_type' =>  'ring_advantage',
    'tax_query' =>  array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'issue_RingAdvantage',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => $current[0]->slug,
        ),
    ),
);
```

How can I implement a query that ALSO gets the topic associated with `ring_advantage`?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question, but to *show* the "topics" assigned to a post, you can use [`get_the_term_list()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_term_list/) or [`get_the_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) to have a custom output.

Comment: I ended up using `wp_get_post_terms()`. I still don't fully understand the difference between all these functions: `wp_get_post_terms`, `get_terms`, `get_term_meta`, `get_post_meta`, `get_the_terms`, and `wp_get_post_terms` (I am sure there are more). They seem so similar, yet work all differently. Do you happen to have a helpful resource outlining the difference?

Comment: You'll need to check the WordPress developer resources (or code reference) to learn more about those functions.. and the Codex might also have a less technical details/guide for you. But what I can tell you is, `wp_get_post_terms()` and `get_the_terms()` basically do the same thing, but the former gives you the ability to provide custom args which are passed to `WP_Term_Query` - the class which handles terms query. And these functions both would actually end up with the `get_terms()` which is a "shortcut" to `WP_Term_Query::query()`.. and with `get_terms()`, post ID is optional.

Comment: The other two functions deal with metadata and used for retrieving a meta value - `get_term_meta()` is for terms (e.g. Categories and Tags), while `get_post_meta()` is for posts (Posts, Pages, CPT).